# Cannot Php artisan serve cause of cannot redeclare class Composer

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I can't run using php artisan serve cause of :

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit4783eae8fdb0bbd7059e05caa6aed997 in /var/www/html/project/config/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php 
>    Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Heres is my `autoload_static.php`:

```
class ComposerStaticInit57efd0b78daf784a291fa20fc5e6edcd
{
    public static $files = array (
        '0e6d7bf4a5811bfa5cf40c5ccd6fae6a' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php',
        '667aeda72477189d0494fecd327c3641' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php',
        '1d1b89d124cc9cb8219922c9d5569199' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php',
        '3919eeb97e98d4648304477f8ef734ba' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php',
        '5255c38a0faeba867671b61dfda6d864' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php',
        '2c102faa651ef8ea5874edb585946bce' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php',
        'bd9634f2d41831496de0d3dfe4c94881' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/polyfill-php56/bootstrap.php',
        'a0edc8309cc5e1d60e3047b5df6b7052' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php',
        'c964ee0ededf28c96ebd9db5099ef910' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php',
        'e7223560d890eab89cda23685e711e2c' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/psy/psysh/src/Psy/functions.php',
        'f18cc91337d49233e5754e93f3ed9ec3' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/laravelcollective/html/src/helpers.php',
        '37a3dc5111fe8f707ab4c132ef1dbc62' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php',
        'f0906e6318348a765ffb6eb24e0d0938' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php',
        '58571171fd5812e6e447dce228f52f4d' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php',
    );

}
```

already try composer install and update but still didnt work at all. anyone know ?

Comment: try : `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: composer update then try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @JigarShah already try and still didnt work

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz still same error

Comment: @Axel delete your vendor directory and composer install

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz already rm -r vendor/ and composer install still same, so for now tryin to clone the repo, ill tell you if it work, btw thanks for the help sir.

Comment: So the problem is wrong step while compose require internvention/image. 

i didnt check the app/config.php first. should comment the provider and the aliases. 

i think the case is solve. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is wrong step while compose require internvention/image. i didnt check the app/config.php first. should comment the provider and the aliases. i think the case is solve. thank you everyone.